# Problems loading data into SPSS from Mysql/Excel

Tags: mysql, numbers, spss

I am (unfortunately) new to SPSS and Mysql.

I am attempting to load a large dataset from a mysql database into SPSS. 
(I am using Mysql workbench 5.2 and SPSS 20)

When I attempt to load in the data directly from Mysql to spss (using File --> open database --> new query steps), the data of two columns is changed.
From a number between 1 to +/-900, this becomes something like this data as shown below.

```
240521392178    939537201
-9223371512865344500    -9223371511333126100
57174608329009  60680123449395
-9223371512865606700    -9223371511333126100
223341522994    943128629
-9223371512865344500    -9223371511342025700
227636951345    825294899
```

If I load this same data into Excel the data loads correctly. 
I am then able to get it in to SPSS if I then load the data into SPSS from an excel file.

However when I attempt this my two time columns change. 
This is a selection of the data in Excel:

```
00:48   01:38
00:40   01:00
02:49   01:32 
00:28   00:56
00:44   02:16
```

However once it has been loaded (using the file --> open --> data option)  into SPSS I get the following:

```
994296:48:00.00 994297:38:00.00
994296:40:00.00 994297:00:00.00
994298:49:00.00 994297:32:00.00
994296:28:00.00 994296:56:00.00
994296:44:00.00 994298:16:00.00
```

Can anyone please help me.

If any information is missing please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete solution to the question. I am trying to give some guidelines how this could be solved.

Time values could be tricky. Time values are saved as numerics in all programs. But the interpretation differs. For example SPSS stores time value as the number of seconds. Excel stores time value in days (please check this one). I do not know about MySQL.

So first, you have to find out from documentation how time values are stored in MySQL. If you will know how SPSS and MySQL store time values probably you will be able to convert MySQL time values to SPSS time values by some arithmetic transformation.

Other option would be to read time values from MySQL as text (string). And then convert the text to SPSS time values in SPSS.